Ingress controller could not find my tls secrets (developing locally using docker desktop kubernetes)
I am developing locally using Docker Desktop kubernetes. I created the ingress-nginx pods by applying the official yaml file from ingress-nginx documentation, which is v1.11.2. The problem is, from the nginx controller logs, it shows
W0828 06:55:47.990075       7 controller.go:1438] Error getting SSL certificate "default/tls-secret": local SSL certificate default/tls-secret was not found. Using default certificate
I0828 06:55:47.999359       7 main.go:107] "successfully validated configuration, accepting" ingress="default/ec-example-app"
I0828 06:55:48.001713       7 store.go:440] "Found valid IngressClass" ingress="default/ec-example-app" ingressclass="nginx"
I0828 06:55:48.002013       7 backend_ssl.go:67] "Adding secret to local store" name="default/tls-secret"

What I have done before applying the Ingress config
Creating a self signed certificate following this official guide from ingress-nginx controller
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout tls.key -out tls.crt -subj "/CN=exampleapp/O=exampleapp" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS:exampleapp"

Adding the crt and key to kubernetes secrets
kubectl create secret tls tls-secret --cert tls.crt --key tls.key

Verify if the secret is created successfully
➜  ~ kubectl get secret
NAME            TYPE                DATA   AGE
client-id       Opaque              1      28h
client-secret   Opaque              1      28h
cookie-secret   Opaque              1      28h
tls-secret      kubernetes.io/tls   2      22m

Verify there is content in the secret
➜  ~ kubectl describe secret tls-secret
Name:         tls-secret
Namespace:    default
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Type:  kubernetes.io/tls

Data
====
tls.crt:  1216 bytes
tls.key:  1704 bytes

Applying my ingress.yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ec-example-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-rewrite-log: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - exampleapp
      secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: exampleapp
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: ec-example-app
                port:
                  number: 80

Make sure I have the DNS entries in /etc/hosts
    127.0.0.1   exampleapp

Doing curl -v on http:// shows 308 Permanent Redirect
➜  ~ curl -v exampleapp
* Host exampleapp:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:80...
* Connected to exampleapp (127.0.0.1) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: exampleapp
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Date: Wed, 28 Aug 2024 07:26:04 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 164
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://exampleapp
<
<html>
<head><title>308 Permanent Redirect</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>308 Permanent Redirect</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host exampleapp left intact

Doing curl -v on https://
➜  ~ curl -v https://exampleapp
* Host exampleapp:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to exampleapp (127.0.0.1) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with exampleapp port 443
curl: (35) schannel: next InitializeSecurityContext failed: CRYPT_E_NO_REVOCATION_CHECK (0x80092012) - The revocation function was unable to check revocation for the certificate.

Doing curl -kv on https://
➜  ~ curl https://exampleapp -kv
* Host exampleapp:443 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 127.0.0.1
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:443...
* Connected to exampleapp (127.0.0.1) port 443
* schannel: disabled automatic use of client certificate
* ALPN: curl offers http/1.1
* ALPN: server did not agree on a protocol. Uses default.
* using HTTP/1.x
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: exampleapp
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
>
* Request completely sent off
* schannel: server closed abruptly (missing close_notify)
* Closing connection
* schannel: shutting down SSL/TLS connection with exampleapp port 443
curl: (56) Failure when receiving data from the peer

When I open up in Chrome it says ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
I have looked up many of the threads regarding this issue on SO and github issues. None of them helped. Anyone familiar in this area that could help ? Would be very much appreciated.

Check the Ingress and the Secret are in the namespaced resources.
They can only work within their namespace. So in your use case you need to put both of them (Ingress and Secret) in the same namespace.

@HemanthKanchumurthy, there's no namespace specified if I understand but using default, unless I missed. Hiromasa, could you share if you needed to create Certificate? Just to check, you might need tls-secret secret being created by Certificate.

@HemanthKanchumurthy Yes, they are in the same namespace, which is default
@ChachatonelHashimotto I am just following the openssl command to create the tls-secret. How do I know if I need a Certificate to create the tls-secret, sorry I am not very familiar with the ssl areas

Hi @Hiromasa can you please refer this
https://medium.com/@sobha366/step-by-step-guide-to-generating-kubernetes-tls-secrets-using-openssl-commands-635eade99a3c

@HemanthKanchumurthy Thanks!. I have followed the guide, but got an error saying SSL certificate "default/tls-secret" does not contain a Common Name or Subject Alternative Name for server , Then i tried adding subjectAltName in my openssl.cnf, now it shows the same error again saying Error getting SSL certificate
